# Cannot login again after resuming crawl. Cookies are not sticky after resuming scrapy

Tags: cookies, scrapy

I have a CrawlSpider, the code is below. I use Tor through tsocks.
When I start my spider, everything works fine. Using init_request I can login on site and crawl with sticky cookies.

But problem occurred when I stopped and resumed spider. Cookies became not sticky.

I give you the response from Scrapy.

```
=======================INIT_REQUEST================
2013-01-30 03:03:58+0300 [my] INFO: Spider opened
2013-01-30 03:03:58+0300 [my] INFO: Resuming crawl (675 requests scheduled)
............ And here crawling began
```

So... callback=self.login_url in def init_request is not fired!!!

I thought that scrapy engine didn't want to send again request on login page. Before resuming scrapy I changed login_page (I can login from every page on site) to different that not included in restrict_xpaths.

Result is - After resuming I cannot login and previous cookies are lost.

Does anyone have some assumptions?

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider,Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.loader import XPathItemLoader
from scrapy.contrib.loader.processor import TakeFirst, MapCompose, Join, Identity
from beles_com_ua.items import Product
from scrapy.utils.response import get_base_url
from scrapy.utils.url import urljoin_rfc
from scrapy.utils.markup import remove_entities
from django.utils.html import strip_tags
from datetime import datetime
from scrapy import log
import re
from scrapy.http import Request, FormRequest

class ProductLoader(XPathItemLoader):
    .... some code is here ...


class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'my'
    login_page = 'http://test.com/index.php?section=6&type=12'

    allowed_domains = ['test.com']
    start_urls = [
        'http://test.com/index.php?section=142',
    ]
    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('.',),restrict_xpaths=('...my xpath...')),callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )
    def start_requests(self):
        return self.init_request()

    def init_request(self):
        print '=======================INIT_REQUEST================'
        return [Request(self.login_page, callback=self.login_url)]


    def login_url(self, response):
        print '=======================LOGIN======================='
        """Generate a login request."""
        return FormRequest.from_response(response,
            formdata={'login': 'mylogin', 'pswd': 'mypass'},
            callback=self.after_login)

    def after_login(self, response):
        print '=======================AFTER_LOGIN ...======================='
        if "images/info_enter.png" in response.body:
               print "==============Bad times :(==============="
        else:
           print "=========Successfully logged in.========="
           for url in self.start_urls:
            yield self.make_requests_from_url(url)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

        entry = hxs.select("//div[@class='price']/text()").extract()
        l = ProductLoader(Product(), hxs)
        if entry:
        name = hxs.select("//div[@class='header_box']/text()").extract()[0]
        l.add_value('name', name)
        ... some code is here ...
        return l.load_item()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `init_request(self):` is available only when you subclass from `InitSpider` not `CrawlSpider`

You need to subclass your spider from InitSpider like this

```
class WorkingSpider(InitSpider):

    login_page = 'http://www.example.org/login.php'
    def init_request(self):
        #"""This function is called before crawling starts."""
        return Request(url=self.login_page, callback=self.login)
```

But then remember that you can't define `Rules` in `initSpider` as its only avaiable in `CrawlSpider` you need to manually extract the links

Comment: I do not why, but my code is working well with init_request. It fails only when I try resume spider.

Comment: your code is working because when u start spider then u are manually calling `self.init_request()` in `start_urls`, which is called when you start crawler only once . so when u stop and resume then `start_url` ia not called again and your `init_request` is not called . With your current code you can have any name instead of `init_request` becaus eu are manually calling so name does not matter but from call it automatically you need to subclass from init_spider